# Как в React в onclick вызвать функцию из другого файла

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Имеется дропдаун с несколькими пунктами. Каждый пункт должен выполнять определенное действие. Громоздить всю логику в файле, который должен только рендерить меню, не хочу.

Существует ли что то типа `"onclick={export file.function}"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объявить метод на экспорт в том файле:

```
export function ExportMe() {

}
```

Импортируйте:

```
import {ExportMe} from './MyFileWithExportedFunction'
```

Используйте:

```
onclick={ExportMe}
```

Вероятно, можно даже так написать:

```
onclick=import {ExportMe} from './MyFileWithExportedFunction'
```

Comment: Шикарно отработало!!!!! Спасибо!!!!!

Comment: @ColdPol рад помочь)

Comment: Новая проблема вылезла... Как передать событие onClick из одного класса в обработчик событий другого класса? (Клик по кнопке в Дропдауне должен открыть Модальное окно). Реализовано в разных классах (файлах). У модального окна 2 состояния  show: false, show: true. Если бы кнопка находилась внутри класса Modal, то было бы как то так: onClick={() => this.setState({ show: true })}

Comment: @ColdPol отдельным вопросом лучше задайте. Больше людей увидит.

Answer (score 0):

Для подобный кейсов существует динамический импорт

В этой статье все очень подробно описано.

https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/loading-components-asynchronously-in-react-app-with-an-hoc-61ca27c4fda7

Comment: Ссылка не рабочая?